# Removing Elements with a certain id in a vue.js method

Tags: vue.js

By reading the question, you are probably already thinking; Just use plain JavaScript and add:

```
document.getElementById('yourId').classList.add('hide');

.hide {
display: none;
}
```

I added similar code to my program, and I am not getting any results.
Here is a codepen for the project I'm making.
Program View: https://codepen.io/dickeddocks/full/gKNMLW 
Editor View: https://codepen.io/dickeddocks/pen/gKNMLW

If you just play the game and keep clicking "attack" till the round ends, you will get an alert and the log at the bottom will disappear. If you click "attack" again, another round starts but the log from the last round reappears.

My solution to fixing this was to add an id to each `<li>` element and the id would change after the round reset.

Then, I tried adding these two solutions to the function which would reset the app. ('#log0' being the id I chose to give to all the list elements generated in the first round. Then, a counter variable would run making all the list elements from the next round '#log1' -> '#log2' and so on).

```
document.getElementById('log0').classList.add('hideLog');
document.getElementById('log0').style.display = "none";

.hideLog {
display: none;
}
```

But for some reason all `<li>` items with `#log0` keep appearing

P.S I dont want anyone to read all the code in the codepen, if you know a simple solution off the top of your mind, I'll happily take that.

Update: Ive even tried using Jquery's .addClass and still no results.

Comment: Seems like this fixes it? Basically you need to reset `turns`.  Remember, Vue is data driven. You don't want to be modifying the DOM yourself. https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/zaVBbG?editors=1010

Comment: If you're trying to hide something, add a boolean variable and use v-show or v-hide.

Comment: @bert, holy cow I forgot you could just reset the array. Thats such an efficient solution, thank you so much :)

Comment: @Devon also yes I could have done that instead of adding classes etc.